# REST: Single representation of responses for two REST requests that return object/objects of type 'A'

Tags: rest, api, web-services, api-design, restful-url

I have two REST URLs....

1. {host}/data/account

that returns a collection of accounts. We can model response for this request as shown below as a collection of accounts

```
{
    "items": [{
        "prop_name_1": "val_1",
        "prop_name_2": "val_2",
            |
            |
            |
            |
        "prop_name_n": "val_n",
        "Links": [{child_links}]
    }],
    "Links": [{
        {self_link},
        {pagination_links}
    }]
}
```

2. {host}/data/account/{particular_account_id}

that returns only a single account. We can model response for this request as only a single account as shown below

```
{
    "prop_name_1": "val_1",
    "prop_name_2": "val_2",
        |
        |
        |
        |
    "prop_name_n": "val_n",
    "Links": [{child_links}]
}
```

Now the question is, can I model responses for both these requests as only collection of accounts instead of two different representations?

The reason for doing it is the simplicity of parsing the response and also consistency in representation. Also, a collection can be used to represent a single object as well. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, your're correct. Returning a collection containing a single element is a common API design decision.

Comment: How does a REST URI differ from a non-REST URI? REST APIs should also [not have typed resources](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven). REST (as HTTP ideally) uses content-negotiation to exchange data in well-defined formats (coupling to the media-type not the API). What you are asking has nothing to do with REST but with RPC over HTTP.

Comment: @RomanVottner, I have updated the question. I think I did not clearly explain my question. This edit would I guess.

Comment: If you want to follow a REST architecture model you should aim on reusing either an existing media type that is expressive enough to deliver the content or implement one on your own, register it with IANA and then transform data into your representation. This is, of course, not the easiest task though it avoids clients from coupling to the API on the long run and therefore allow you to modify the server side without breaking clients as both sides only couple to well-defined media types